# How to store passport strategy used in session?

Tags: node.js, express, session, passport.js

I have a web-app that uses local and apple strategies with passport.

I'd like to store which type of passport "strategy" a user used to login. That way when they return to the site and load their session, I can check with the 3rd party authenticator (i.e.- Apple) to ensure that their session hasn't been revoked.

I understand that I could potentially track such things in my users table, but I'm looking for a way that ties to a session rather than a user account, since a user could have multiple sessions (across multiple devices).

I'm using `Node.js` with `Express` & `Passport.js`. For my session store I'm using `connect-mssql-v2`.

Answer (score 1):

This has been up for a while and no one has replied, so I'll post my workaround in case it helps the next guy. I won't accept my own answer in case someone comes along with a better option:

I modified my store in my session to use a custom `genid` function; by default, it would appear that express' session configuration by default just creates a record with uids. You can generate your own uids for sessions by setting the `genid` attribute.

```js
{
     // ...
     genid: (req) => {
          // 37 chars long total
          // 32 characters (base 64, so 24) random, plus we want to note the authentication method for use later. 'APPL'/'PASS'/'GOOG'
          const uuid = uid.sync(24); // use UUIDs for session IDs
          const route = (req?.url?.split('/') ?? [undefined]).pop();
          let str = uuid;
          switch (route) {
               case 'apple':
                    str = 'APPL+' + uuid;
                    break;
               case 'google':
                    str = 'GOOG+' + uuid;
                    break;
               default:
                    str = 'PASS+' + uuid;
                    break;
          }
          // console.log(str);
          return str;
     },
     // ...
}
```

The basic principle is that I'd use the request object to determine the server endpoint that the user connected to. I'd then insert a 4-digit identifier code onto the front of the generated uid, with a '+' as a seperator. Then, just by looking at the session, you know which auth provider was used.

My router looked like this:

```js
// Login
router.post('/login', 
     passport.authenticate('local', {
          failureRedirect: '/auth/failure',
     }), 
     controller.success
);
router.post('/login/apple', 
     passport.authenticate('apple', {
          failureRedirect: '/auth/failure',
     }),
     controller.success
);
router.post('/login/google', 
     passport.authenticate('google', {
          failureRedirect: '/auth/failure',
     }),
     controller.success
);
```

Comment: Hopefully this is helpful to the next guy; if there're any questions please feel free to inquire. Goodluck 